# Qtablewidget overwritten keyPressEvent but cell not updated before it is executed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have overwritten the keyPressEvent method in Qtablewidget. It works fine but when the cell contents is changed and it the method is triggered for instance over Key return is pressed then it seems that the old value of the Cell is taken over rather than the one that is just written into it.

Even Enter doesn't update it.

Which is quite strange but maybe because I am overwriting the method so it does only what I have specified.

So I am wondering what is the method to call that updates a cell?

This is my class

```
class CustomTableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(CustomTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)

def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    key = event.key()

    if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return or key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
        #sth done here for which I need the cell content            
    else:
        super(CustomTableWidget, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could show your code.

Comment: Sorry about my answer it is incorrect below this comment. The value is updated!! I don't know why it wasn't working before.